# Arduino : I am trying to convert the string coming via Bluetooth into an char array

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, bluetooth, char

Hello Everyone : I am trying to convert the string coming via Bluetooth into an char array
what i want to is that get the string (which will be a word) from the Bluetooth and the convert it into a char array: 
for example:

Arduino Receives from Bluetooth : `water`

I want this to be converted into : `char arrayThing[30] = {'w','a','t','e','r',0};`

Following is the code what I am trying to do please help me out in this guys

`char arrayThing[30];
        arrayThing[30]= Serial.read();`

```
 for (int index = 0; index < 30; index++)
 {
    Serial.write(arrayThing[index]);
 }
   //  char arrayThing[30] = {'w','a','t','e','r',0};
    ouijaPrint(arrayThing);
    homeing();//Go back to home after each massage is printed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial.read() returns max. 1 character, which you put into the desired position of your char array. Serial transmission is slow, so you better do not wait, but transmit an end-of-message character, e.g. < newline > aka. '\n'

```
char arrayThing[30];
byte pos = 0; 
void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available() {
      arrayThing[pos] = Serial1.read();  
      if (arrayThing[pos] == '\n') {
         arrayThing[pos] = 0;  // text end 
         pos = 0; // prepare to receive the next text line
         Serial.println(arrayThing); // work with the result 
      } else {
          if (pos < 29) pos++; // prepare for next character
      }
   }
}
```

Serial1 is your Bluetooth, Serial your debug output (for this test)

Comment: You never *need* Arduino String objects, and they seldom really help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help , One Question:  I have to type the entire word via the Bluetooth terminal, and it will convert my word into the array i want ? Im new to this you know

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Probably it depends on your "Bluetooth terminal", which might have a "Send" button and an option to choose the terminator. ( CR / LF / CRLF / none ) ? ( usually,  '\n' is LF (line feed) )

Comment: Can I send you my entire code so you can see where is the problem because I cant figure out what seems to be the problem , when I enter via Serial Monitor the letter, it gets displayed on the serial monitor but its not working as its suppose to

Comment: No, Thanks. But you can reduce your "entire code" to a minimal but complete sample, showing the problem. My answer code is just lacking the definition of Serial1   with pin definitions for your bluetooth connection,  and setup() to initialize Serial and Serial1. You could use that instead and add these 5 lines ...

Comment: yes ,  I got that , So basically the code is about the ouija board , controlled by the stepper motors found here ... https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Ouija-Board/

Comment: Im making this controlled by Bluetooth

Comment: `void ouijaMessage()
{//char arrayThing[30] = {'h','e','l','l','o','1','8',0};
char arrayThing[30];
byte pos = 0; 
  if (Serial.available()) //if (Serial1.available()) {arrayThing[pos] = Serial.read();  //arrayThing[pos] = Serial1.read(); 
      if (arrayThing[pos] == '\n') {arrayThing[pos] = 0;  // text end 
         pos = 0; // prepare to receive the next text line Serial.println(arrayThing); // work 
 with the result  } 
      else 
      {if (pos < 29) pos++; // prepare for next character}ouijaPrint(arrayThing);
        homeing();//Go back to home after each massage is printed }`

Comment: `void ouijaPrint(char* charArray)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i <= MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++){
    Serial.print(charArray[i]); //Debug the array as we move
    if(charArray[i] != 0){
      ouijaDelay();
      moveToSymbol(charArray[i]);
      ouijaDelay();  
      //if(digitalRead(switch_x_right) == LOW || digitalRead(switch_y_bottom) == LOW)
      //homeing();
    } //Only move if there if valid data, if not let the loop run out.
    else break;
  }
  return;
}`

Comment: so every thing works great if I just type the array in my code , but its  not working this way , I want to like type  a word, the word gets into my array and the rest of the work is done by my code